# UICollectionview which loads photos from library.How to pass Image to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a `collectionview` which loads images from photo library using photos framework.I have added a segue named `saveSelected` for the purpose of passing the selected image to another `viewController` NoteDetailViewController.How can I pass the same

My AddPhotoViewController is given below

```
import UIKit
import Photos
private let reuseIdentifier = "PhotoCell"
class AddPhotoViewController: UIViewController , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate ,UINavigationControllerDelegate ,UICollectionViewDataSource ,UICollectionViewDelegate
{

@IBOutlet weak var photoAlbum: UICollectionView!

var TakenImage : UIImageView!

var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!
var photosAsset: PHFetchResult!
var assetThumbnailSize: CGSize!
let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController! = UIImagePickerController()
var cameraon : Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let collection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.SmartAlbum, subtype: .SmartAlbumUserLibrary, options: nil)

    var i = 0
    repeat
    {
        if let first_Obj:AnyObject = collection.objectAtIndex(i)
        {
            self.assetCollection = first_Obj as! PHAssetCollection
        }
        i++
    }while( i < collection.count)



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera)) {
        if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Rear) != nil {
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
            imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
            presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: {})
            cameraon = true
        } else {
            print("Rear camera doesn't exist")
        }
    } else {
        print("Camera inaccessable")
    }

}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    TakenImage.image  = image
    if (cameraon)
    {
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(TakenImage.image!, 0.6)
        let compressedJPGImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedJPGImage!, nil, nil, nil)

    }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    print("User canceled image")
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        // Anything you want to happen when the user selects cancel
    })
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    if let layout = self.photoAlbum!.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
        let cellSize = layout.itemSize

        self.assetThumbnailSize = CGSizeMake(cellSize.width, cellSize.height)
    }

    //fetch the photos from collection
    self.photosAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(self.assetCollection, options: nil)

    self.photoAlbum!.reloadData()


}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

/*
// Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be selected
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
return true
}
*/


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if (segue.identifier == "savePhoto")
    {
        if let controller : NoteDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? NoteDetailViewController
        {
            controller.imageView.image = TakenImage.image
        }
    }
/*    if (segue.identifier == "saveSelected")
    {
        if let controller2 : NoteDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? NoteDetailViewController
        {
             if let cell = photoAlbum.cel as? PhotoAlbumCollectionViewCell
             {


            }
        }

    }*/
}


func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    var count: Int = 0

    if(self.photosAsset != nil){
        count = self.photosAsset.count
    }
    print("\(self.photosAsset.count)")
    return count
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell: PhotoAlbumCollectionViewCell = photoAlbum.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PhotoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoAlbumCollectionViewCell

    //Modify the cell
    let asset: PHAsset = self.photosAsset[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset

    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: self.assetThumbnailSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info)in
        if let image = result {
            cell.setThumbnailImage(image)
        }
    })

    return cell
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



}
func collectionView(collectinView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

}

}
```

How should I modify the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and prepareForSegue to achieve this?

Comment: Is you have added segue with `collectionViewCell` in you `stroyboard` or with `ViewController`?

Comment: @Nirav I've added segue in storyboard

Comment: I am asking is segue connected with `viewController` or `CollectionViewCell` check that?

Comment: @Nirav segue is connected with CollectionviewCell

Comment: can anyone help me with a working solution???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `segue` with `CollectionViewCell` so there is no need to write any thing in your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method, Change your code like this in `prepareForSegue` method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "saveSelected")
    {
        let cell = sender as! PhotoAlbumCollectionViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! NoteDetailViewController
        destVC.asset = self.photosAsset[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset
    }
}
```

Now create one global object with name `asset` in `NoteDetailViewController` like this

```
var asset: PHAsset!
```

Now add like below code in your `viewDidLoad` of `NoteDetailViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: self.assetThumbnailSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info)in
        if let image = result {
            self.imageView.image = image
        }
    })
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The image clarity is lost when passed to NoteDetailViewController.How can I solve this

Comment: @VineethKrishnan Welcome ..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can't set any imageviews or outlets before the controller is loaded, so you've to modify your segue code and the other controller to have an image that will be sent when segued.

```
if (segue.identifier == "savePhoto")
    {
        if let controller : NoteDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? NoteDetailViewController
        {
            controller.image = TakenImage.image
        }
    }
```

then modify the segued class:

```
class NoteDetailViewController: UITableViewController {
    var image: UIImage!
}
```